# How to extract only floats(decimals) from a string that also includes integers

Tags: php, regex

I can't find the appropriate regex to extract only floats from a string.
Consider the following string:

```
$string = "8x2.1 3x2";
```

I want to extract 2.1, I tried the following but this gives me integers and floats:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9,]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?/', $string, $matches);
```

i then tried using  `is_float` to check for floats but this also returns the integers for some reason. Any ideas? 
thanks

Comment: Do you know how that regex works? What does this part mean? `(?:\.[0-9]*)?`

Comment: Try: `/[0-9,]+\.[0-9]+/`

Comment: Also `$matches` will contain strings and `is_float()` will always return `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches float and integers, and even strings consisting of just commas.

- `[0-9,]+` - 1 or more digits or `,`
- `(?:\.[0-9]*)?` - one or zero sequences of `.` + zero or more digits.

You need

```
/\d+\.\d+/
```

That will match 1+ digits, `.` and 1+ digits.

Or, to also match negative and positive floats, add an optional `-` at the beginning:

```
/-?\d+\.\d+/
```

**Details**

- `-?` - one or zero hyphens (`?` means *match one or zero occurrences*)
- `\d+` - one or more digits (`+` means *match one or more occurrences*, `\d` matches a digit char)
- `\.` - a literal dot (since a dot in a regex is a special metacharacter, it should be escaped to denote a literal dot)
- `\d+` - one or more digits

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/fZMIf4):

```
$string = "8x2.1 3x2";
preg_match_all('/\d+\.\d+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
// => Array ( [0] => 2.1 )
```

A bonus regex that will also match only float numbers with optional exponent (a variant of the regex at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)):

```
 /[-+]?\d+\.\d+(?:e[-+]?\d+)?/i
```

Here, you can see that an optional `+` or `-` is matched first (`[-+]?`), then the same pattern as above is used, then comes an optional non-capturing group `(?:...)?` that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the following sequence: `e` or `E` (since `/i` is a case insensitive modifier), `[-+]?` matches an optional `+` or `-`, and \d+` matches 1+ digits.

Comment: Sure, I added details.

Comment: How about negative floats, do you need those? Probably not considering the example data.

Answer (score 6):

Consider this simple example:

```
<?php
$input = "8x2.1 3x2";
preg_match('/\d+\.\d+/', $input, $tokens);
print_r($tokens);
```

Matches "one or more digits, followed by exactly one full stop and again one or more digits".

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2.1
)
```